# WPF derived Grid control control template

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have an MyGridControl derived from DataGrid.

I want to put 2 Command buttons on the right top corner (Not in the Grid, above the Grid) of the Grid so that these 2 buttons will appear for each of the Grid i will put on the WPF window.

How can i write a Control template for it?

Or Is there any other way of doing it?

One important thing, I can do it using Custom Control but i want MyGridControl should be derived from DataGrid not UserControl, so that all DataGrid properties can be easily exposed to my Window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt get **this**...

> One important thing, I can do it using Custom Control but i want MyGridControl should be derived from DataGrid not UserControl, **so that all DataGrid properties can be easily exposed to my Window.**

Going back to your query, you could create a usercontrol and "adorn" the Grid in that user control in a GroupBox and override its `HeaderTemplate` to host two buttons to the top-right coner

Or

You could affix a popup to top right corner of the grid to host the buttons.

Comment: Hi Angel, Thanks for the solution. is it possible to add adorn on top of the Grid? I don't want it inside the Grid Header. Can you please give me any sample?

Comment: Hi Angel, After searching on adorn control, i found this post http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/josh_smith/archive/2008/09/15/introducing-a-new-xamdatagrid-behavior-displayadorningeditors.aspx Thanks for the help. i am still in search of how to add adorn button on top right corner of my datagrid user control. <UCDatagrid></UCDataGrid> which is derived from DataGrid control. From your answer i found that it's adorn i need to search for. i am accepting your answer.